# WebService with Tornado.web and Authentication. Do you have Example?

Tags: python, authentication, tornado

I'm brand new in Tornado.web.

I just write an webservice in python with tornado. He is consumed by an desktop application. I want to require that the application communicates only after being authenticated.

I searched for examples, but can't found any applicable for my case.

Comment: I've done some tornado authentication for one tornado/motor/mongodb project, [this example](http://tornadogists.org/5251927/) helped a lot. Basically, the answer depends on what kind of authentication you are trying to do: if it is third party like facebook or twitter - they are supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just add the `@tornado.web.authenticated` decorator, and specify to your application a `login url` where you specify the `debug=True`

```
settings = dict({
    "template_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"templates"),
    "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"static"),
    "cookie_secret": "make it harde to guess ;) ",
    "xsrf_cookies": True,
    "debug": False,
    "gzip": True,
    "login_url": "/#login",
    "site_url":"http://localhost:8000",
})
```

and finally, you inherit your classes from the one that controls the cookies existance:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.removeslash
    def get_current_user(self):
         return self.get_secure_cookie("name_of_your_cookie")
```

example:

```
class Test(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def post(self):
        user = self.get_secure_cookie("name_of_your_cookie")
        # the rest of the code...
```

what will happens now, everytime someone tries to enter to a link that will use `Test`, the application will look if the `cookie` exists, else, it will be **redirected** to the `login_url`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this authentication can't be made by login. My application do not work with users.

Comment: what kind of authentification you want

Comment: So, I have an application that is distributed for all our clients. This is one service. This service needs to comunicate yourself with our python webservice that uses tornado. But this application don't use any user and password. This is not your objective. This application needs to comunicate for get any informations that is required in my clients. Any way to authenticate? I think in any thing kind "token".

Comment: what about converting the mac adresses (since it's unique) to base64 (to use them in url) and then you just `self.request.uri` and get the client?